# Am I doing anything wrong with my kitten?

Tags: cats, feeding, junior-pets

I have a kitten that was born on Thanksgiving. Her mother passed away, so I’ve been taking care of her. She whines a lot and I try to comfort her and she gets scared at first and then comes over and purrs. Her eyes are still shut, but it looks like she tries to open them a little and and shuts them again. I try to feed her from a bottle and she won’t eat. Any suggestions on how to get her to eat and survive until she gets older to take care of herself? She also just tries to clean her face often and it’s usually just her eyes

Comment: You should get professional advice immediately, e.g. consult your vet or local rescue shelter. Taking care of very young kittens is a difficult task, and things can go wrong quickly. If you are unsure about something, do not hesitate to call a vet and get advice.

Answer (score 7):

I’m really glad that you’ve stepped up to take care of this poor little thing but you must get her to a rescue center or an emergency vet asap.

Newborn kittens can’t regulate their own body heat and rely on their mothers for that. Till the time you get her the medical help she needs, place her next to a soft toy of some sort with something warm in there. Look up Kitten Lady on YouTube. She has amazing videos on how to provide immediate care for newborn kittens. Here is [one](https://youtu.be/hsUbkKAuVSU) she did about new born kitten rescue. She usually places a toy that simulates the mother - it’s warm, has a heartbeat and is soft and furry.

Also the kitten’s eyes and ears are shut at birth. They only start to see and hear the world about 10-12 days after birth. The kitten needs nutrition round the clock. They also cannot poop or  with pee on their own. It has to be stimulated and mom usually does this by licking them.

Again, take her to get professional help right away! You can adopt her after she is a little bigger.